# Is it possible to configure currencies in a multi-currency scratch org?

Tags: unit-test, salesforcedx, multi-currency

I'm writing SalesforceDX unit tests that need to use either `USD` or `EUR` in `Account.currencyIsoCode`. So I created a scratch org from this `project-scratch-def.json` configuration that specifies the `MultiCurrency` feature:

```
{
  "country": "US",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "features": ["MultiCurrency"],
  "orgPreferences": {
    "enabled": [
      "S1DesktopEnabled"
    ],
    "disabled": []
  },
  "orgName": "MyOrg",
  "adminEmail": "admin@my.org"
}
```

Running a test fails with this error:

```
System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0;
first error: INVALID_OR_NULL_FOR_RESTRICTED_PICKLIST, Account Currency:
invalid currency code: EUR: [CurrencyIsoCode]
```

Turns out that creating an org with the feature `MultiCurrency` only has one currency (`USD`) configured, which can be checked in the developer console with:

```
SELECT IsoCode FROM CurrencyType
```

I googled, but couldn't find a way to configure the active currencies in the `project-scratch-dev.json`, so I figured I would just insert them in the tests themselves, like so:

```
static testMethod void testEuros() {
  List<CurrencyType> euros = [select IsoCode from CurrencyType where IsoCode = 'EUR'];

  if (euros.size() == 0) {
    CurrencyType euro = new CurrencyType();
    euro.IsoCode = 'EUR';
    euro.IsActive = true;
    euro.IsCorporate = false;
    euro.DecimalPlaces = 2;
    euro.ConversionRate = 1.0;
    insert euro;
  }

  Account acc = new Account();
  acc.Name = 'TestAccount';
  acc.CurrencyIsoCode = 'EUR';
  insert acc;
}
```

But this attempt is cut short by `sfdx force:source:push` refusing to push the source with the following error:

```
DML operation Insert not allowed on CurrencyType
```

So the question is... How does one properly configure currencies in a multi-currency scratch org?
Preferably in the `project-scratch-def.json`, but definitely without opening the org and making manual changes, that is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither DML nor [Metadata API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_unsupported_types.htm) support Currency (Exchange) Inserts.

The tree/bulk api does, though, see this answer for a programmatic way to enable different currencies in a scratch org:

[How to prep scratch org with currencies](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/231871/how-to-prep-scratch-org-with-currencies)

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In this release I foun an error creating MultiCurrency scratchOrgs with "feature" configuration in "project-scratch-def.json" file.

To solve it, I have activated the MultiCurrency from setting config file section:

```
{
  "orgName": "Demo Company",
  "edition": "Developer",
  "language": "en_US",
  "features": ["Communities","ServiceCloud","ServiceUser","ContactsToMultipleAccounts"],
  "settings": {
    **"currencySettings":{
      "enableMultiCurrency": true
    },**
    "experienceBundleSettings": {
      "enableExperienceBundleMetadata": true
    },
    "orgPreferenceSettings": {
      "networksEnabled": true
    }
  }
}
```